ema for different currency pairs in Indicator
I am trying to write a script where I use ta.ema(close,200) function for multiple currency pairs eg.
If close > ema for AUDUSD it should give a "Bullish" signal and
if close < ema for USDJPY it should give a "Bearish" signal ect ect
I identified 14 currency pairs.
Is it possible to have a ema for each pair ?
I tried the following code but I get just one result for all the pairs
EMA_LEN = input(200)

ticker01 = input.symbol("AUDUSD", "Ticker")           
// = input.symbol("ADAUSD", title="", group="Portfolio Asset #1", inline="Ticker 1")
ticker01EMA = request.security(ticker01 , ta.ema(close,EMA_LEN) 
//ta.ema(close,EMA_LEN) 
ticker01TREND = close > ticker01EMA ? "Bullish" : close < ticker01EMA ? "Bearish" : "Neutral"  


request.security requires: symbol, timeframe and expression
try this
EMA_LEN = input(200)
ticker01 = input.symbol("AUDUSD", "Ticker")
ticker01EMA = request.security(ticker01 , timeframe.period, ta.ema(close,EMA_LEN))
ticker01TREND = close > ticker01EMA ? "Bullish" : close < ticker01EMA ? "Bearish" : "Neutral"

and for the table:
var table tbl = table.new(position.top_right, 2, 40)// 40 is max call request security
table.cell(tbl, 0,0, ticker01TREND)
table.cell(tbl, 1,0, ticker01)


Thank you very much I appreciate your help. Its bedtime for me but I will try your script tomorrow and let you know. Have a great day

I could not wait. Your scripts works GREAT. Thank you so much !!!!!!!!!!!

Morning Sir. i notice that when you change pairs the "Bullish" / "Bearish"  signal  also change. Why idoes it happens?

example with two pairs
EMA_LEN = input(200)

ticker01 = input.symbol("AUDUSD", "Ticker")
ticker01EMA = request.security(ticker01 , timeframe.period, ta.ema(close,EMA_LEN))
ticker01TREND = close > ticker01EMA ? "Bullish" : close < ticker01EMA ? "Bearish" : "Neutral"
ticker02 = input.symbol("EURUSD", "Ticker")
ticker02EMA = request.security(ticker02 , timeframe.period, ta.ema(close,EMA_LEN))
ticker02TREND = close > ticker02EMA ? "Bullish" : close < ticker02EMA ? "Bearish" : "Neutral"


var table tbl = table.new(position.top_right, 3, 40)// 40 is max call request security

table.cell(tbl, 0,0, ticker01TREND)
table.cell(tbl, 1,0, ticker01)
table.cell(tbl, 0,1, ticker02TREND)
table.cell(tbl, 1,1, ticker02)


Hi, Gu5tavo, my code is exactly the same, but it even with 2 pairs the signal is not constant when you pick different pairs in the same timeframe.

Even when I add "D" instead of timeframe.period the result changes when I select a different currency pair

Hallo, thank you for your help, If you find a solution to this problem will you please let me know.
